# how to get Mysql database value in Jframe table without creating coding for Jtable

Tags: java, mysql, swing, netbeans, jframe

i have create student table like following fields Stuid, studname, mark1,mark2 in Mysql Database. and also create a table using JFrame( source,design) after that i wrote the  following code in source side, then drag the table from the Swing controls.

```
public void DbConnection(){
       try
{
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");//Connection establishment to the database
String username = "root";
String password = "root";
String Database = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/project";


Conn = DriverManager.getConnection( Database, username, password );
System.out.println("*** Connect to the database ***");


String Query = "Select * from  StudentMaster";


Statement smnt = Conn.createStatement();
ResultSet results = smnt.executeQuery( Query );
ResultSetMetaData metaDt = results.getMetaData();
System.out.println(metaDt);

int cols = metaDt.getColumnCount();
for(int i=1;i<cols;i++){
    columnNames.addElement (metaDt.getColumnName(i));
}
 while(results.next()){
     Vector row= new Vector(cols);
     for(int i=1;i<=cols;i++){
         row.addElement(results.getObject(i));
        }

     data.addElement(row);
 }
results.close();
smnt.close();

Conn.close(); //Close Connection to the database
    }
catch(Exception e)
{
    System.out.println(e);
}
}
```

it's connecting with Mysql Database, but it's not showing the DBtable value in Jframe Table. how i can get the value in table(Jframe table control) without creating a code for table.  if i double click on table i don't know where i write table code.

Comment: Why you are not giving correct answers the points?

Answer (score 3):

If you are using NetBeans it is easy

**Step 1**

1. right click on javaApplication in project window
2. Select New > Others > Persistence ->(Right Side) Entity Classes From Database [Select]
3. Click Next
4. Now Select Database Connection from ComboBox and Add database table you want to bind with `jTable` from 'Available Tables' listbox to 'Selected tables' listbox
5. Finish

Here you made a class which you can bind with your `jTable`

**Step 2**

1. Right Click on your jTable
2. Select Binding
3. Click on elements [it will open 'Bind jTable.element' window]
4. There click on 'Import Data from Form' named Button
5. Select Database and Table from given ComboBoxes and click OK
6. Now There you can see two list boxes named as 'Available' and 'Selected' in Selected List    Box there you can see all attributes of your database table listed.
7. If you want to remove any attribute from this just select that and click '<<' button
8. Re Arrange attributes using 'up' and 'down' buttons
9. Click OK now you can see your `jTable` bound With database
10. Finished

Comment: Do you realize that this question is more than two years old and that the poster of the question hasn't logged in for more than two years? It's fine to answer older questions, but I wouldn't expect a lot of gratitude in this case.

Comment: @Erwin Bolwidit I understand ,But it may be helpful for many others. anyway thanks for editing.

Answer (score 0):

This is an easy way to achieve your homework, by creating a reusable `TableModel` able to display content of any `ResultSet`:

```
public class MyModel extends AbstractTableModel {
   String[] headers = {};
   ArrayList<String[]> rows;

   public MyModel() { 
      rows = new ArrayList<String[]>();
   } 

   public int getColumnCount() {
      return headers.length;
   }

   public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) { 
       if (row < 0 || row >= rows.size()) return "N/A";
       if (col < 0 || col >= headers.length) return "N/A";
       return rows.get(row)[col]; 
   }

   public int getRowCount() { 
      return rows.size(); 
   }

   public String getColumnName(int col){ 
       if (col < 0 || col >= headers.length) return "N/A";
      return headers[col]; 
   } 

   public void fill(ResultSet rs) {
       //Setting Headers
       ResultSetMetaData md = rs.getMetaData();
       int cols = md.getColumnCount();
       headers = new String[cols];
       for(int i = 1; i < cols; i++) {
          headers[i - 1] = md.getColumnName(i); 
       }

       // Setting rows
       rows.clear();
       while(rs.next()) {
          String[] row = new String[cols];
          for(int i = 1; i < cols; i++) {
             row[i - 1] = rs.getString(i);
          }
          rows.add(row);
       }
       this.fireTableDataChanged();
   }
}
```

Hope it helps, good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I can tell on button and window is opened.

```
     {
      try
      {
         Class.forName("java.sql.DriverManager");
    Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/project","root","tiger");
    sql="select * from (table name)";
    Statement st=con.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery(sql);
    jdis.getModel();
            }
             catch(Exception e)
      {JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e.getMessage());}

  }      
 }
```